# Use jquery to select and localise leaflet layer name

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I am using leafletjs - http://leafletjs.com/

I need to localise the layer and overlay text to the users selected language.

The leaflet code is like this:

```
// create map
map = L.map('map', {
    center: [dlat, dlng],
    zoom: dzoom,
    layers: [osmap, markersgroup, POIgroup, mylayergroup, fencesgroup]
});
var baseLayers = {
    "Normal": osmap,
    "Satellite": satellite
};

var overlays = {
    "All Markers": markersgroup,
    "Online Markers": onlinegroup,
    "Offline Markers": offlinegroup,
    "Live Markers": livegroup
};
```

As you can see the overlay names are set "All Markers", "Online Markers" etc. I need to be able to select these and change to french, spanish strings.

The html is rendered like this:

```
<div class="leaflet-control-layers-overlays">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" checked="">
<span> All Markers</span>
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector">
<span> Online Markers</span>
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector">
<span> Offline Markers</span>
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector">
<span> Live Markers</span>
</label>
</div>
```

Could i select the `span` in each `label` and rename it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did this

```
$(".leaflet-control-layers-overlays span").eq(0).text(strings[strLang].allMarkers);
$(".leaflet-control-layers-overlays span").eq(1).text(strings[strLang].onlineMarkers);
$(".leaflet-control-layers-overlays span").eq(2).text(strings[strLang].offlineMarkers);
$(".leaflet-control-layers-overlays span").eq(3).text(strings[strLang].liveMarkers);
```

Comment: Came here hoping for a better solution. It would be nice if these spans were tagged with the internal leaflet ID at least.